# If the record exists in target but doesn't exist in source, i need to delete it

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete, dml, sql-merge

So, i have two tables, the target table and the source one. I need to delete the rows that exists in the target table, but doesn't exists in the source table.

And the code:

```
MERGE INTO (SELECT id_car_bk, car_brand_bk, car_type_bk, new_car
              FROM car_catalog_backup) CB
USING (SELECT id_car, car_brand, car_type FROM car_catalog) C
ON (CB.id_car_bk = b.id_car)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (CB.id_car_bk, CB.car_brand_bk, CB.car_type_bk)
  VALUES
    (C.id_car, C.car_brand, C.car_type)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET CB.car_brand_bk = C.car_brand;
```

Comment: So, what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: i don't know how to delete those rows

Comment: WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE is the ideal way if you want to manage it within the MERGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
DELETE car_catalog_backup b 
 WHERE not exists 
        ( SELECT 0
            FROM car_catalog c 
           WHERE b.id_car_bk = c.id_car );
```

or

```
DELETE car_catalog_backup b 
 WHERE b.id_car_bk not in 
        ( SELECT c.id_car
            FROM car_catalog c );
```

assuming `car_catalog` is `the source`, and `car_catalog_backup` is `the target`. The First one is preferable, since it's more performant.

If your aim is to find out with a `MERGE` statement similar to your case, then use the following

```
MERGE INTO car_catalog_backup a
USING (SELECT id_car, car_brand, car_type, car_brand_bk 
         FROM car_catalog
         JOIN car_catalog_backup
           ON id_car_bk = id_car
         ) b
   ON (a.id_car_bk = b.id_car)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET a.new_car = 1
   DELETE
   WHERE a.car_brand_bk != b.car_brand 
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT
    (id_car_bk, car_brand_bk, car_type_bk)
   VALUES
    (b.id_car, b.car_brand, b.car_type)
```

to delete the records matched for `id` columns ( `a.id_car_bk = b.id_car` ) but not matched for `brand code` columns ( `a.car_brand_bk != car_brand` ) as an example.

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/ZLQT71151)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete from target
Where not exists 
( 
    Select 1
    From source 
    Where join of source and target
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a left join:

```
DELETE target 
FROM target LEFT JOIN source 
ON target.someid = source.otherid 
WHERE source.otherid IS NULL;
```

Comment: doesn t work can u be more specific or try something else?

Comment: This is the right syntax for Oracle. Join the 2 tables on a common column and delete the rows that don't match: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.1-en/delete.html

Comment: Andrei GH, mr. forpas gave you link to mysql database delete statement.

Comment: akk0rd87, i know, but i tried to understand how can i apply it on my code